# ¿Cómo adjuntar credenciales de certificado SSL al enviar E-Mail?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo electrónico y me devuelve este error:

*El certificado remoto no es válido según el procedimiento de validación.*

Buscando solución encontré  esta línea, supuestamente desactiva la validación del certificado:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
pero me devuelve:

*El buzón de correo no está disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)*

Lo que me hace pensar es que si envió el certificado de autentificación en el intento de enviar el correo el servidor va a responder positivamente.

Mi código C#

```
public bool EnviarMailNotificacion2(string subject = "Prueba envio notificacion", string body = "Prueba envio notificacion", string emailDestiny = "efrainmejiasc@gmail.com")
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient servidor = new SmtpClient();
        mensaje.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sdfsd@dsfdfsdf.com");
        mensaje.Subject = subject;
        mensaje.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mensaje.Body = body;
        mensaje.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mensaje.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mensaje.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(emailDestiny));
        servidor.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ssssss@xxxx.com", "dfsdfsdfsdfs");
        servidor.Port = 587;
        servidor.Host = "mail.sdfsdfsdfs.com";
        servidor.EnableSsl = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        servidor.Send(mensaje);
        mensaje.Dispose();
        result = true;
      }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```